# Mocha WebStorm integration

Tags: typescript, ide, mocha.js, webstorm

**WebStorm** has this nifty feature that when you write tests with **Mocha** using the standard `describe()` and `it()` keywords it will add a small arrow next to the keywords to run them manually.

**Here's the issue,** I need to do extra-pretest-setup across tests so I have custom methods for describe, it. They are called `setupNewSuite` and `createNewTest` > due to name change WebStorm no longer shows the little arrows.

I want WebStorm to treat `setupNewSuite` as if its `describe` and `createNewTest` as if its `it`.

(P.S it might be possible to trick it using the same original names but if that's the case I'll just drop this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the IDE is statically analyzing the source code looking for known code patterns when detecting the test files. 
Obviously, `setupNewSuite` and `createNewTest` wrappers are not known, so your tests are not detected and can't be run from the sidebar. There are no workarounds unfortunately.

We have a feature request for providing support for custom test/suite names, [WEB-37848](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37848), please feel free to vote for it.